# Java dispatch soapmessage and proxy

Tags: java, soap, proxy, dispatch

I create a Java client for a webservice using this [link](https://alesaudate.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/how-to-dynamically-select-a-certificate-alias-when-invoking-web-services/) but I need to connect to a Proxy (with user and password) before call the webservice.

At other times, I created a Proxy and open a httpconnection directly but now, I don´t know how put a Proxy with a Dispatch< SOAPMessage > that calls to "invoke(soapMsg)" method.

Any idea?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. With Dispatch only is necessary to specify:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("https.proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", proxyUser);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", proxyPassword);
```

Also is necessary to specify the "Endpoint address property" that is the WS address.

```
dispatcher.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://123.145.67.89:8080/name");
```